# How do I prove that $\lim_{x\to0^+}\log_a x= -\infty$?

Tags: calculus

> $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} \log_a(x)=-\infty , a > 1$$

How do I prove this limit in a formal way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $-B$ be a negative number with arbitrarily large absolute value $B$. Let $x_B=a^{-2B}$. Then, for all $x$ with $0<x < x_B$ we have

$$\log_a (x) < \log_a \left(a^{-2B}\right) = -2B < -B.$$

This proves that

$$\forall (-B) < 0 \; \exists x_B \ge 0 \textrm{ such that } \forall x\in\left(0, x_B\right)\textrm{ it holds that } \log_a (x)< -B$$

which is equivalent to the statement

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \log_a (x) = -\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

Outline of my proof: The idea is that for any  $a>1, \ $ if you look at the graph of $y = \ log_a{x}, \ $ whenever you halve $x, \ y \ $ goes down by $ log_a{2}, \ $ which is greater than $0 \ $ because $a>1. \ $ So if you just keep halving $x, \ $ this has the effect on $ \ log_a{x} \ $ of subtracting the same positive value from $y. \ $ This continues with no lower bound on the y-values: they "go down to -infinity".

Formally, we must show that, $ \forall \ \gamma < 0, \ \exists \ \epsilon > 0 $ such that $ 0<x<\epsilon \implies \ log_a{x} < \gamma$.

I will assume you already know how to prove that $log_a{x}$ is a strictly increasing function for $a>1.$

By the archimedean property of $ \Re $ (see Rudin's PMA Thm 1.20(a) ), $ \exists \ $ a positive integer $N \ $ such that $ -N log_a{2} < \gamma.\ $ Note that $\ log_a{2} > 0=log_a{1} \ $ because the function $log_a{x}$ is strictly increasing.

Setting $ \epsilon = \frac{1}{2^N} \ $ then gives us the result:

$0<x<\frac{1}{2^N} \implies log_a{x} < log_a{\frac{1}{2^N}} = -Nlog_a{2} < \gamma.$

Comment: I feel like I've done something wrong, but looking at my answer, I don't see it. Perhaps it's correct :O